# Sweet Alert 2 with AJAX content

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, sweetalert

I am trying to make a [Sweet Alert](https://sweetalert.js.org) dialog with an AJAX response as content but I am not sure how to use their fetch() function.

According to their documentation I could use the option `content` to set an element.

```
swal({
    title: 'Test Dialog',
    icon: 'info',
    content: fetch('http://some.url')
  })
```

Where I should see the DOM content of that URL as the dialog content. Instead I get of course: nothing:

[image: test dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like  Sweet Alert natively supports ajax. You'll just have to call Sweet Alert from fetch.

```js
fetch('data:text/html,Some%20dynamically%20loaded%20content').
then(response => response.text()).
then(function(data){

  swal({
    title: 'Test Dialog',
    icon: 'info',
    text: data
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://sweetalert.js.org/assets/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I should use `content` instead of `text` since text will show only as plain text and I need to show HTML content.

Comment: @Maramal just replace "text: data" with "html: data".